# Boolean Issues with shapes from Gravity sketch

Tags: modifiers, vertices, faces

I use Gravity Sketch to build models and then render in Blender. Sometimes I use basic functions in Blender to add textures or add modifiers, but nothing crazy. I have recently discovered the Boolean modifier, which is incredibly useful as there is no way to cut into a surface/object in Gravity sketch. However, I have to use simple shapes otherwise it doesn't seem to work (again, I am very limited on knowledge on the Boolean modifier). I am trying to use this design (purple) on a large surface (green) and  I can't seem to get the Boolean to work. After some digging, I believe the issue is that the surfaces of the line segments (purple) are too complex but I can't seem to figure out how to simplify them in a way that it works for the Boolean. I have attached a link to the file below as it may to easier to play with it a little to understand what I am referring to. I could be completely wrong in my assessment of what is wrong or it could be multiple issues, I am no expert! Please Help!

[image]

Disclaimer:

The endcaps of the line segments are broken in a bunch of pieces. This happens for some reason when transferring from Gravity Sketch. You can ignore those.[image]

Comment: Share your file. http://blend-exchange.com  Also, consider using the built-in tools to send your pictures. Some won't be interested in being taken off site to see your issue.

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Thank you both, I originally had the image embedded and I somehow messed it up. Should be good now.